# How can I access the localhost of linux subsystem from my Windows browser?

Tags: windows, ubuntu, apache-2.4, bash

I have a Windows 10 system. I have Linux subsystem (Bash) in the same system. I have installed apache server in linux subsystem. How can I access the localhost of linux subsystem from my Windows browser?

Answer (score 2):

Localhost always refers to the system you are on.  If your Apache server is restricted to localhost, you will not be able to access it from any other host without a tunnel.  You can use `ssh` to open a tunnel if you have enabled the openssh server.

Normally, you would browse to your Linux systems external address. Depending on your router (DHCP/DNS servers) you may be able to browse by name.  Otherwise browse to the IP address of the server.  If you open up a terminal session on the Linux server, the command `ip addr show` should list your IP addresses.  The one you want likely starts `192.168.`